# what is the example of $x_n$

Tags: real-analysis

$x_n\gt0,$

$x_n^\frac1n $ converges, but $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ diverges.

what is the example of this?

and how to prove

'$x_n\gt0,$  $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$converges$\to x_n^\frac1n $ converges'?

Comment: $x_n=2+(-1)^n$ should work.

Comment: $\{x_n\} = \{1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,\dots\}$ so $\{x_{n+1}/x_n\} = \{3,1/3,3,1/3,\dots\}$